# Apple iWork Mime Types

Tags: mime-types, iwork

I was wondering what the mime type for iWork's Pages is? And also what the mime type is for the rest of the software in the iWork suite? I looked around online and I didn't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like Apple doesn't much care, since installing iWork does not add any mime type information to any of its system mime-type info reps (in /etc/cups and /etc/apache2), "Get Info" on an iWork file shows no mime-type, etc.  The only hint I've found is in Page's info.plist (a copy's online [here](http://leefindlow.com/images/iWork-09/Pages/Info.plist)) which mentions:

```
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>pages</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages</string>
            </array>
```

and a similar one for filename-extension "template", with "-sfftemplate" as the suffix instead of "-sffpages".

Answer (score 40):

I recently needed this for work and ended up just uploading some files and querying the mimetypes. I found the following:

- keynote: application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey
- pages: application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages
- numbers: application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers

---

#### 2021 Update

Please note that this answer is now outdated and the following content types have been approved by IANA:

- [application/vnd.apple.pages](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apple.pages)
- [application/vnd.apple.keynote](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apple.keynote)
- [application/vnd.apple.numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apple.numbers)

Comment: what's the meaning of the "sff" prefix? Is it related to the different versions of Apple Iwork?

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: pages: application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages --> Not working for android

Comment: Although you should probably `accept` both the old `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey` version as well as the new `application/vnd.apple.keynote`, since old files will use the former.

Answer (score 9):

```
  application/vnd.apple.keynote
  application/vnd.apple.pages
  application/vnd.apple.numbers
```

Just got it approved with IANA. You will find the list at the below link.
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml.

You can use mime-db https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db to validate using javascript

Answer (score 4):

This URL shows some other types in case new readers need it:

[Apache Jira Issue TIKA-588](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-588)

application/vnd.apple.keynote, application/vnd.apple.pages, application/vnd.apple.numbers

Answer (score 2):

Actually, those files are all a masked zipfile. So, some systems might indicate their mimetype simply as `application/zip`.