# How extract iWorks suite mimetype with Exiftool

Tags: python, alpine-linux, exiftool, iwork

I need to extract mimetype with magic number from iWork suite.

How do? Exiftool see ".pages" etc. as "application/zip". But the real mimetype isn't this. 
How can i extract the correct mime?

I can use an validation with python tool if needed.

"Apline for docker".

Thanks for help.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a registered MIME type for these files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454777/apple-iwork-mime-types So what output would you expect?

Comment: What mimetype do you want to be returned?  It looks like it would be pretty easy to edit the [.exiftool_config](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/config.html) to return what you want.  Or would each ".pages" file have a different mimetype depending upon the contents?

Comment: The mimetype of iwork files for Apple are: keynote: application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey
pages: application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages
numbers: application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers. I've an file without extension and forn exctract it PDF i need to take the mime from magic number.

Comment: @Ed From what I can find out, a `.pages` file is just a zip file, similar to a `.docx` file.  There is no magic number to differentiate it from a zip file.  It's probably not possible to identify one that doesn't have an extension  by editing the config file.  Since exiftool is able to identify a `.docx` that doesn't have an extension, it might be possible for the author of exiftool to add that ability.  You might want to ask on the [exiftool forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum) and provide an example `.pages` file that exiftool can't identify as such.

Comment: @StarGeek thaks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil Harvey has "Improved identification of Apple iWork files" in exiftool version 10.96.  Check to see if that works for you.

Comment: I've ask to Phil Harvey, and he released this version. But without extension the identification doesn't work.

Comment: Send him a file that doesn't work and he should be able to update it better.

Comment: He has relese the version with the fix. Thank for your help in his forum.